# cffile alternative, I need to upload without form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion, form-submit

So I want to upload a file to the server using ajax, so the form is not submitted. Cffile requres the filefield attribute, but as there is no form object passed to coldfusion that doesn't work. I can store the value entered by the user as a variable in javascript, and pass that variable to cf. How can I use this variable to upload my file? Thanks.

**EDIT**
Solved by submitting to iframe.

Comment: Submit the form to a hidden iframe and handle your form upload as you normally would (with cffile).

Comment: You could use the [jquery-form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin

Comment: jquery-form example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit the form to a hidden iframe and handle your form upload as you normally would.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [cffileupload](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec18238-7fd0.html) tag (embeds a flash widget for uploading) , or take advantage of XMLHttpRequest level 2 ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2)) via the method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8736436/511250).

Comment: Unfortunately, browser support is an issue with me :/ Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you uploading images?
You could try uploading to a canvas tag client side using javascript.

Then ajax post the base64 png encoded contents of the canvas.

Further reading and examples:

[How to upload/POST multiple canvas elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712497/how-to-upload-post-multiple-canvas-elements)

[How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

[Resizing an image in an HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303690/resizing-an-image-in-an-html5-canvas)

[Resize image before upload, but upload synchronously (not ajax). Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743082/resize-image-before-upload-but-upload-synchronously-not-ajax-is-it-possible)

http://coding.pressbin.com/84/File-API-Resize-photo-before-upload/

Comment: I need to upload essentially anything. Definitely more than just images.

Comment: Scratch this then - it works great for images, not so much for everything else