# Uploading a file with AJAX and CFFILE

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, cffile

I have a small form where I would like to upload a file to my CF Server. I have been able to make this work in the past by submitting my CFFORM via a traditional actionpage. However I would like to upload the file using AJAX instead.

I am receiving an error on my processing page as follows: The cffile action="upload" requires forms to use enctype="multipart/form-data" even though I have defined my form as such.

From google'ng around, I think it may be becasue Cffile requres the filefield attribute, but as there is no form object passed to coldfusion. [Possible Similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852813/cffile-alternative-i-need-to-upload-without-form-submit) . I don't really like the solution posted though.

Is there anyway I could get around this error?

Here is my AJAX:

```
<!---Script to upload file link --->     
<cfoutput>
<script>
$(function(){
//Add a new note to a link
$("##upload-file").submit(function(event){
   // prevent native form submission here
   event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: $('##upload-file').serialize(),
            url: "actionpages/file_upload_action.cfm",
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.loader').show();
            },
            complete: function(){
                 $('.loader').hide(3000);
            },
            success: function() {
                PopulateFileUploadDiv();
                $("##upload").val('');
                $("##response").append( "File successfully Uploaded." );
              }    
        });
        return false;           
    });
});
</script>
</cfoutput>
```

My Form:

```
<form method="post" name="upload-file" id="upload-file" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <input tabindex="0" size="50" type="file" id="upload" name="upload" accept="image/bmp, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/tiff, image/gif, image/png, text/richtext, text/plain, text/css, text/html, application/rtf, application/msword, application/x-excel, application/zip, multipart/x-zip, audio/wav" value="Upload an additional file" />

      <br />
      <input name="submitForm" id="submitForm" type="submit" value="Attach File To Ticket">

      </form>
```

Processing Page:

```
<!---File Upload Logic --->

        <!---CFFile Tag located in template file --->
        <!---CFFile code --->
        <cffile action="upload" filefield="upload" destination="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ticket-uploads\" accept="image/bmp, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/tiff, image/gif, image/png, text/richtext, text/plain, text/css, text/html, text/xml, application/x-zip-compressed, application/xml, application/mspowerpoint, application/powerpoint, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation , application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/x-mspowerpoint, application/octet-stream, application/pdf, application/rtf, application/msword, application/x-excel, application/zip, multipart/x-zip, audio/wav" nameconflict="makeunique">

       <!---Retrieve Uploaded filename --->
        <cfoutput>
        <cfset Uploaded_File_Name = #cffile.ServerFile#>
        </cfoutput>

        <!--- Add file details to file_uploads table --->
        <cfquery name="uploads" datasource="#datasource#">
        insert into file_uploads (ticket_id, file_path)
        values(#form.ticket_id#, '#Uploaded_File_Name#')
        </cfquery>
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: You should be using `cfqueryparam` in your query. NEVER trust user provided data.

Comment: Yes, certainly, as Scott said. Use the tag `cfqueryparam`. All it takes is one mischievous submission to destroy lots of valuable work and data,. change the values line of your query to `VALUES(<cfqueryparam cf_sql_type="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.ticket_id#">,<cfqueryparam cf_sql_type="cf_sql_varchar" value="#uploaded_file_name#">)` Note the lack of single-quotes. `cf_sql_type` dictates their presence. However, this has no impact on the problems your having, just stops sql injection. use `CFQUERYPARAM` for literally every `#variable#` in every query.

Comment: Yes I agree. I'm slowly going though all my queries and changing them over. I literally have hundreds to change. Not fun. @cfqueryparam - this post has php processing. Are you suggesting the my cffile code would stay the same, I would just use that FormData class?

Comment: @BrianFleishman I thought that maybe the jquery-related tips in the replies such as perhaps contentType and processData

Comment: @BrianFleishman - It is not a quick task, not matter how you do it, but there are tools like [varScoper](http://varscoper.riaforge.org/) that make it a *little* easier. *RE: this post has php processing* I think you can ignore the PHP stuff, the important part is the js ie sending the file using ajax. You might also find this thread helpful: [jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload). It explains the new options in greater detail.

Comment: I looked through the comments and I can't seem to figure out what to implement here. Kind of a newbie to Jquery. Can you provide some suggestions?

Comment: Nothing to do with your question at all, but `cfoutput` tags are not needed as often as you might think. They are not needed around the `cfset`. If fact you do not even need the extra variable. You could simply use `cffile.ServerFile` directly in your cfqueryparam.

Answer (score 6):

As @cfqueryparam mentioned in the comments, the key is the javascript code. In particular, the `contentType` and `processData` settings. The action page can be written in any server side language.

Just to demonstrate, the [example in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22621393/104223) works fine. At least in newer browsers. Aside from dumping the status to a `div`, the only thing I changed was the input name. That is because FILE is a keyword in CF.

**Upload**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Upload Form</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitForm() {
            console.log("submit event");
            var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileinfo"));
            $.ajax({
              url: "action.cfm",
              type: "POST",
              data: fd,
              enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
              processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
              contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
            }).done(function( response ) {
                // display response in DIV
                $("#output").html( response.toString());
            })
           .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                // display error in DIV
                $("#output").html(errorMessage);
            })            
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" id="fileinfo" name="fileinfo" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
        <label>Select a file:</label><br>
        <input type="file" name="upload" required />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**action.cfm**

```
<cffile action="upload" filefield="upload" 
    destination="c:/temp/" 
    nameconflict="makeunique"
    result="uploadResult">
<!--- Quick and dirty response dump for DEV/Debugging only --->
<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(uploadResult)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I noticed that as well and changed my field name to upload.